# How to edit a message sent in a dm [Discord.JS version 14.14.1]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I attempt to edit the message I get the error:
[image: Error message]

```
const submit = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('submit')
            .setLabel('Submit')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);
const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(submit);
await i.message.edit({ components: [row] });
```

I have tried fetching the message then trying to edit it but get the same error.

What I expect to see is just the message being edited to disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of looking up I tried simply searching for the dm channel then searching for the message. This worked and fixed the issue.

```
const targetChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === i.message.channelId);
        const msg = await targetChannel.messages.fetch(i.message.id)
        const out = await msg.edit({ components: [row] }).catch(console.error);
```